# Self Joins in Laravel 8 Framework

Tags: database, laravel, web, backend

I'm working on this project were I'm using Laravel 8 as my backend frame work and I have to make a self Join, I have tried out this code but it did not work -the first join is the one I tried but failed- :

```
   public function get_all_medical_centers(){
    $data= DB:: table('medicalcenters')
    ->join('medicalcenters','medicalcenters.id',"=",'medicalcenters.parent_id')
    ->join('countries','medicalcenters.country_id',"=",'countries.id')
    ->join('states','medicalcenters.country_id',"=",'states.id')
    ->join('cities','medicalcenters.country_id',"=",'cities.id')
    ->select('medicalcenters.*', 'countries.name as country_name', 'states.name as state_name', 'cities.name as cities_name')
    ->get();
    return $data;
}
```

The thing is, in the database the medical centers table has some attributes that are the parent of other attributes and I want to get the name of the parent attribute when previewing the children to also preview the name of its parent and not just the id.

the table diagram:
[image]

Comment: do you have an eloquent model of medicalcenters? please provide, it would be easier to add a self relationship to the model.

Comment: can you please explain more I did not get the Idea @AnuratChapanond

Comment: instead of using query builder like you did, you can use eloquent model https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent, do you have them?

Comment: no I don't but I will check them out
thank your sir

Answer (score 1):

If you try to self-join a table then you have to give at least one of them an alias, because otherwise, SQL can't know what you are referring to if you select any column from those tables.

To add an alias to your joined table, you can do this:

```
DB::table('medicalcenters AS medc')
    ->join('medicalcenters AS self','medc.id',"=",'self.parent_id')
```

But this is a hacky solution and for normal relational data in Laravel, eloquent models would better.

---

**Edit Why do you need Aliases on self joins:**

If you join two tables, lets say: `users join posts on users.id = posts.user_id`. You have to specify the join condition. Here this is `users.id = posts.user_id`.

Lets modify this to a self join: `users join users on users.id = users.user_id`. Here the condition is not clear. Is this `users.id` or this `users.user_id` the original table or the self joined table? It's not clear how to join those two tables. So we have to give them different names aka aliases. Like this `users as creators join users as subscribers on creators.id = subscribers.user_id`.

Comment: sir after reading your code I tried it but it did not work sadly did you try it?

Comment: @MohammadAzzam If you don't know what an Alias is I recommend google and reading about basic database functions. Here is a good start: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp 
And this code can't work directly without you editing the table names. It is just an illustration how to to self joins and yes I tested this in Laravel 8 and it works. And I updated my answer to explain why you need aliases.

Comment: thank you I will try it and give you feedback